# Dataset does not reflect new primary key after insert

Tags: c#, dataset, sql-update, auto-increment

This is my first question here and please excuse me with this presenting style.

I have a MySQL table `categories` with following columns:

- c_id (*auto-increment*)
- c_code
- c_name

Here is what I am trying to do;

- dataset contains one table - `categories`
- add a row to dataset (new category)
- update database using `mysqldataadaptor`'s `update()` method
- view dataset entries in a datagridview

Problem is after I insert new row, my dataset's relevant row does not show the last inserted primary key (auto-generated one). But it shows the values.

This is the code where I add new row

```
var dr = ds.Tables["categories"].NewRow();
    dr["c_code"] = "tst123";
    dr["c_name"] = "123tdt";
ds.Tables["categories"].Rows.Add(dr);
```

This is the code where I update database

```
adp.Update(ds.Tables[tempTableName]);
```

and finally this is how I view the dataset **SOON AFTER** above line

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["categories"];
```

PROBLEM:
In the gridview only `c_code` and `c_name` appear there.

How do I get the last inserted `id` to dataset?

Comment: The ADO.NET `DataSet` and `DataTable` do not automatically re-query the database after an insert - that's why you're not getting the newly inserted ID back. You need to either return the ID from the `INSERT` (e.g. by using a stored procedure or something like that), or then you need to re-execute the query to fetch the data, so that the data is being read from the database table again - with the newly inserted `ID` in it.

Comment: You should have put that as an answer. Then I would have looked less like a freeloading donkey :D

Comment: Thanks marc_s. think i need to have a stored procedure, since reloading will result in lot of unwanted overhead. (duplications)

Answer (score 0):

I would guess you have to do a new adp.Fill(ds) to get the ID. You only provide c_code and c_name. Hence, c_code and c_name are the only columns filled in the grid. adp.Update updates your database, it does not reload the entire dataset after an update for obvious reasons.

Comment: thanks WozzeC, appreciate your idea. planing to use marc_s approach. will update here soon

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:
It is in VB but you can see what is going on.

```
mySQLdataAdapter.Update(myDataSet, table)
mySQLcommand.CommandText = "Select Last_Insert_ID();"
lastInsertID = dc.ExecuteScalar()
```

Running this code right after the mysql adapter update provides the last inserted ID for even though i am using a dataset.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the RowUpdated event of the DataAdapter to query the last inserted ID and update the current row:

```
...
adp.RowUpdated += DataAdapter_RowUpdated; // Add this once to your DataAdapter
adp.Update(ds.Tables[tempTableName]);
...

private void DataAdapter_RowUpdated(object sender, MySqlRowUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.StatementType == StatementType.Insert)
  {
     string sql = "select last_insert_id()";
     MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, e.Command.Connection);
     e.Row["c_id"] = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
  }
}
```